# Почему после "import tkinter", могу обратиться "tkinter.Tk()", но не могу обратиться "tkinter.ttk"?

Tags: python

Рабочий код. Python 3.10.0 на виндовс.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
area = ttk.Frame(mainWindow, padding=10)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Из второй строки следует что имя "ttk" является атрибутом модуля "tkinter" так же как имя "Tk". Однако обращение "tkinter.ttk" не работает:

```
import tkinter
mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
area = tkinter.ttk.Frame(mainWindow, padding=10)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\room7364\Documents\pyprogs\tkinterTry\importTtkQuestUnworking.py", line 3, in 
> area = tkinter.ttk.Frame(mainWindow, padding=10)
> AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ttk'

Если "ttk" не является атрибутом "tkinter", то почему тогда работает "from tkinter import ttk" ?

Comment: ttk - это не атрибут tkinter, а вложенный модуль. Видимо модули нужно непосредственно импортировать, они не импортируются автоматически при импорте родительского пакета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это зависит от того, написан ли импорт модулей в библиотечных `__init__.py` файлах.

Похожий вопрос и ответ на него: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60315893/
Цитирую оттуда пример, иллюстрирующий в каких случаях такой импрот срабатывает и в каких не срабатывает:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── numpy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── random
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── mtrand.py
└── tkinter
    ├── __init__.py
    └── ttk.py
```

```py
#numpy/__init__.py:
from .random import RandomState
```

```
#numpy/random/__init__.py:
from .mtrand import RandomState
```

```py
#numpy/random/mtrand.py:
class RandomState:
    pass
```

```py
#tkinter/__init__.py:
```

```py
#tkinter/ttk.py:
class Spinbox:
    pass
```

```py
#__init__.py:
```

```
#main.py:
import numpy
import tkinter

print(numpy.random.RandomState)

try:
    print(tkinter.ttk.Spinbox)
except AttributeError:
    print("Caught an exception!")
    import tkinter.ttk
    print(tkinter.ttk.Spinbox)
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState'>
Caught an exception!
<class 'tkinter.ttk.Spinbox'>
```